# Simplification of conditional probability expression

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following conditional probability expression:

$$
\frac{\frac{P(E|D)P(D)}{P(E)-P(E|D)P(D)}}{\frac{P(\bar{E}|D)P(D)}{P(\bar{E})-P(\bar{E}|D)P(D)}}
$$

I want to simplify it to:

$$
\frac{\frac{P(E|D)}{1-P(E|D)}}{\frac{P(E|\bar{D})}{1-P(E|\bar{D})}}
$$

I already did this on my own but in an overly lengthy way and I was told this should be much more simple. We could remove $P(D)$ from both numerators but other than that I'm pretty lost. I also don't know how to "move" the negation sign from E to D in the denominator part.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts that might help:
\begin{align}
P(\bar E\mid D)P(D)
&= (1 - P(E\mid D))P(D) \\[1ex]
P(E) - P(E\mid D)P(D) &= P(E) - P(E \cap D) \\
&= P(E \cap\bar D) \\
&= P(E\mid\bar D)P(\bar D)
\end{align}

In case you need a derivation of the first fact:
\begin{align}
P(\bar E\mid D)P(D) &= P(\bar E \cap D) \\
&= P(D) - P(E \cap D) \\
&= P(D) - P(E\mid D)P(D)\\
&= (1 - P(E\mid D))P(D)
\end{align}